# Different layout for different screen size

Tags: android, xml, layout, screen-size

**Hey guys..**

I'm redesigning an applicaton and I choose to add support for different layout so to better use the given space. But it in the same time this is an app that will be used most on smartphones *(based on what it can do)*, so I was thinking at something like that:

```
- layout-sw240dp
- layout-sw240dp-land
- layout-340dp
- layout-340dp-land
- layout-sw600dp
- layout-sw600dp-land
```

The *600dp* is the last size I would like to design.
But triyng to build the application on a **Nexus 7 2012** (1280x800 so *sw700dp*) it keeps crashing as soon as it starts! If I create *sw700dp* folders copying there the *sw600dp* layouts it works like a charm!

So the question is: should I provide evry single layout if I choose to create more than one (the usual one in layout folder)?
If I put a standard layout into the mean layout folder, in which case will be it used?

thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to provide layouts for every single screen size. When the user opens your app, if you have specified a layout for her screen size android will show that layout. In any other case it will use the default layout.

This will help you:
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html